# Find space diagonal of a cube with trigomentry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I can calutate the space diagonal of a cubic box using Pythagoras theorem twice. However, how can I find the space diagonal with trigonometry?

I tried this:
A cubic box (picture) with sides $a$.
The triangle in the bottom have hypotenuse $x$ 
\begin{align*}
\cos(45^\circ)=\frac{a}{x} \\
x=\frac{a}{\cos(45^\circ)}=\sqrt{2}a
\end{align*}

The triangle inscribed in the cube have height $a$ and base $x=\sqrt{2}a$. Call the space diagonal $y$ so
\begin{align*}
\cos(45^\circ)=\frac{x}{y} \\
y=\frac{x}{\cos(45^\circ)} = \frac{\sqrt{2}a}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}=2a
\end{align*}
This is wrong, what have I missed?

[image]

Comment: $x$ is longer than $a$ so the final angle is not 45 degrees?

Answer (score 1):

long diagonal angle should be $$\tan { y } =\frac { a }{ x } =\frac { a }{ \sqrt { 2 } a } =\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } $$ $$\tan ^{ -1 }{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \right) ={ 35.264389682755 }^{ \circ  } } $$ not ${ 45 }^{ \circ  }$

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was in assuming that angle is $45^{\circ}$. The "space cross section" forms a non-square rectangle ($x \neq a$). In a non-square rectangle, a triangular dissection via a diagonal does not give you $45^{\circ}$ corner angles (although they are complementary).